# Configuring eslint for VsCode to support type declaration files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am using vsCode for my development and due to the odd nature of my environment I have an api that I can't physically access, currently i'm writing up manual .d.ts files that will act as a psuedo sdk to provide intellisense information and hopefully, linting. Issue is eslint in vscode doesn't seem to want to read those files when telling me what variables are undefined, i'm also not entirely sure how to set that all up correctly?

Update:
I believe I solved the issue, by putting, ***//@ts-check*** at the top of my javascript file, and using the reference path inline xml tslint seems to start working, giving me linting based on my type declaration files. Also using **checkJs: true** in your tsconfig.json works as well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're simply trying to get VSCode to do interactive type-checking, and give you intellisense, for a Typescript-based project.

If that's correct, you shouldn't have to do *ANYTHING* special.

I installed John Papa's "Angular Essentials" extension, which happens to include Typescript support.  Althought I would recommend this, there are a million other VSCode Typescript extensions freely available; most any of them should also do what you need.

I would also install the Chrome Debugger extension, if you haven't already done so.

Q: Does that help, or do you have specific questions that I haven't covered, or specific problems/issues with things you've already tried?

Comment: That's along the right lines, however the project isn't typescript based, though maybe I should switch to that anyway. 
I develop tools for the film industry, predominantly After Effects, which uses a modification of JS called "extendscript", the api is inside adobe, and while I have a pdf I'm trying to setup linting and intellisense using type decleration files (that's what someone else on stack overflow recommended). 
Intellisense I can get to work by putting in a jsconfig.json file, linting however is a different story, currently trying to get tslint to work with js files.

Comment: So you're using "Extend Script".  Q: Have you tried this extension: [ExtendScript Syntax Highlighting for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hennamann.jsx)?  This might also be a possibility: [TypeScript Enabled CEP Development](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2353067)

Comment: Looked into them a while ago, they're fine, the vscode extension isn't great imo, the other one is actually what i'm using as reference, for a few reasons I want to se if I can get my thing to work separately, largely as a mental exercise and also so that I have a far more flexible and ordered system.

Comment: I actually just got something to work, by putting //@ts-check tslint seems to check things, and work with .d.ts files, so far so good!